# How to parse JSON with corrupted string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I generate JSON from many things, images, video, text editor, etc.
And sometimes the editor generates invalid json data, such as whitespace.

On this example `json.parse` doesn't work cause of whitespace.

```
[{"data":"yLI3B33wguU","modalityId":17,"position":2},{"mediaId":"55","modalityId":26,"position":0},{"text":"<p>J&#39;apprends la ponceuse</p>","modalityId":28,"position":3},{"text":"<p>Ma shopping list :</p><ul> <li>perceuse</li>   <li>peinture</li>   <li>pinceau</li>    <li>du matos</li>   <li>...</li></ul>","modalityId":28,"position":1}]
```

Is there any method in JavaScript or C# to solve all corrupted data for `json.Parse`?

Comment: hello, your snippet  evals nicely in the browser console. I don't understand your issue... Do you have an example that fails to eval ?

Comment: Which library are you using to parse the JSON? Does the problem occurs in C#, or JS code?

Answer (score 0):

When I give the data in single quotes to JSON.parse() it worked without any errors.

```
JSON.parse('[{"data":"yLI3B33wguU","modalityId":17,"position":2},{"mediaId":"55","modalityId":26,"position":0},{"text":"<p>J&#39;apprends la ponceuse</p>","modalityId":28,"position":3},{"text":"<p>Ma shopping list :</p><ul> <li>perceuse</li>   <li>peinture</li>   <li>pinceau</li>    <li>du matos</li>   <li>...</li></ul>","modalityId":28,"position":1}]');
```

Just make sure your JSON is a string before passing to JSON.parse();